# What's the shortest abbreviation for "see attachment" or "see enclosed file" in an e-mail?

Tags: abbreviations

I often send empty e-mails with just some attachments. Since some e-mail clients don't show the presence of attachments very clearly, I prefer to indicate that the e-mail contains attachments.

In French I just write "cf pj", which means "see attachment". What's the shortest abbreviation in English for "see attachment", "see enclosed file" or anything equivalent in an e-mail? The best I have found so far is "see [att](http://www.allacronyms.com/ATTM/Attachment/1001145)".

Comment: I don't mean to say that there's anything wrong with your question, but I'd recommend spelling it out when sending emails in English.

Comment: and what's wrong with *see att*? It's just two letters longer than *cf pj*.  You could say *cf att* (one letter shorter) but many folks don't get *cf*.

Comment: I'm not sure how many people understand *att*. I wasn't aware that *cf* is valid in English, thanks that's good to know! *cf att* is indeed pretty good. I asked this question because I was surprised I couldn't find a short expression commonly used for this purpose, and given the answers so far there aren't any.

Comment: "See files" is pretty short.

Comment: "PFA the files" ? PFA - Please find attached, I am sure PFA is used very commonly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess this term came in recently.

**PFA** -  Please Find Attached.

[Acronym Finder](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Please-Find-Attached-%28email-attachments%29-%28PFA%29.html)

Comment: Yes I now see people using it.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't any abbreviation that I'm aware of. But there should be, and perhaps will be.

*Cc:* (carbon copy) and *Bcc:* ([blind carbon copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy)) are used to indicate a comparable type of meta info about a letter or email. In fact, they literally refer to a communication technology that is no longer in widespread use, but the actual function they refer to (sending to multiple recipients) is very much alive. Having a quick way to indicate an email attachment only makes sense. Off the top of my head, and using a similar format, how about *Att:* followed by a number: Att:1. Or by the file type(s): Att:jpg/zip.

Comment: That's quite a good idea.

Comment: In letters, it was common to use *Enc.* (for *enclosed* or *enclosure*) to indicate that there were other things in the envelope. That doesn't have much meaning for email, but I have seen *Att.* used at the bottom of an email for *attachment*.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/att) lists that meaning first, although *Att.* used at the top would probably be taken to mean *Attention* as "For the attention of ..."

Answer (score 3):

encl: 
For enclosure.  Hearkens back to envelopes containing papers.  Similar to .cc and .bcc which are no longer literal but are in widespread use for electronic communication.

Answer (score 2):

The absolute shortest?  Leave it empty, and hope that the recipient notices the little icon that shows there's an attachment.

But if that's unacceptable, *see attachment* is the shortest.  There is no widely recognised abbreviation.  At least, not one that *I'd* recognise.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, there's "encl:" which seems to make sense, due to convention, but I've recently seen these two: Attch, and Att'd. I vote for "Attch."

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please note that it is mandatory to attach any support/evidence to back up your claims. Please review our help center (http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to get additional information